# Upload photos to Facebook Sales group album with graph API, using the Source field and not URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to create an album to the SALES groups in Facebook ? when I use the graph API explorer to fetch the user's groups it only brings back the user groups and not the sales groups he / she is part of

Command I used is get > v2.7 > me/groups and it returns

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Shadow Creek Columbus Indiana",
      "privacy": "SECRET",
      "id": "647651662006143"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "NjQ3NjUxNjYyMDA2MTQz",
      "after": "NjQ3NjUxNjYyMDA2MTQz"
    }
  }
}
```

My second question is, if I were to create an album in the above group and add photos to it using the URL I am able to, however I have a phonegap app and that would be loading the images from the local and not from web, so I need to use the Source field instead of URL. However I am not able to test the same using the explorer. What value should I specify in the Source field ?

Comment: These days the Graph API will only let you post to groups you're an administrator of.

Comment: So is there any other way to upload albums to the sales groups ?

Comment: Not within Facebook's terms of service, no.

Comment: That's a bummer !!!

Comment: thanks for the information ... appreciate it